# Appium IOSDriver times out, but launches iPhone simulator

Tags: appium

My AppiumDriver code is simple enough:

```
var options = new AppiumOptions();
                options.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "iOS");
                options.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "iPhone XR");
                options.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "13.0");
                options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "safari");
                options.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AutomationName, "XCUITest");

                var driver2 =
                    new IOSDriver<AppiumWebElement>(
                        new Uri($@"http://192.168.0.41:4723/wd/hub"),
                        options,
                        new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0));
```

Appium (running on Mac) launches an iPhone simulator on my Mac machine

```
appium -a 192.168.0.41 -p 4723
```

But the IOSDriver constructor never completes, it just times out with exception after 120 seconds (or whatever value I put in there).

This is the output from Appium

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.14.2
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: 192.168.0.41
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 192.168.0.41:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session
[HTTP] {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone XR","platformVersion":"13.0","browserName":"safari","automationName":"XCUITest"},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"iOS","browserName":"safari"}]}}
[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone XR","platformVersion":"13.0","browserName":"safari","automationName":"XCUITest"},null,{"firstMatch":[{"platformName":"iOS","browserName":"safari"}]}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1568747029537 (14:03:49 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[Appium] Could not parse W3C capabilities: 'deviceName' can't be blank
[Appium] Trying to fix W3C capabilities by merging them with JSONWP caps
[BaseDriver] The capabilities ["deviceName","platformVersion","automationName"] are not standard capabilities and should have an extension prefix
[Appium] Appium v1.14.2 creating new XCUITestDriver (v2.116.3) session
[Appium] Capabilities:
[Appium]   deviceName: iPhone XR
[Appium]   platformVersion: 13.0
[Appium]   automationName: XCUITest
[Appium]   platformName: iOS
[Appium]   browserName: safari
[debug] [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:dev... and MJSONWP desired capabilities {"platformName":"iOS","devi... were provided
[debug] [BaseDriver] Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"appium:dev...
[BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 23f10772-5375-4c81-9536-5805132fc717
[debug] [XCUITest] Current user: 'patrick'
[XCUITest] iOS SDK Version set to '13.0'
[XCUITest] Simulator udid not provided
[XCUITest] Using desired caps to create a new simulator
[debug] [simctl] Creating simulator with name 'appiumTest-AA3CE20A-10E7-44EF-A669-2EE6D93D3047-iPhone XR', device type id 'iPhone XR' and runtime id 'com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-0'
[iOSSim] Constructing iOS simulator for Xcode version 11.0 with udid '42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD'
[XCUITest] Created simulator with udid '42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD'.
[XCUITest] Determining device to run tests on: udid: '42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD', real device: false
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'xcodeDetailsRetrieved' logged at 1568747031680 (14:03:51 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[XCUITest] Safari test requested
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'appConfigured' logged at 1568747031681 (14:03:51 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[XCUITest] Continuing without capturing device logs: iOS Simulator with udid 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD is not running
[XCUITest] Setting up simulator
[debug] [iOSSim] Setting common Simulator preferences to {"RotateWindowWhenSignaledByGuest":true,"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":false}
[debug] [iOSSim] Updated 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD Simulator preferences at '/Users/patrick/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist' with {"DevicePreferences":{"42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD":{"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":false}},"RotateWindowWhenSignaledByGuest":true,"ConnectHardwareKeyboard":false}
[iOSSim] Booting Simulator with UDID 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD...
[iOSSim] Simulator with UDID 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD booted in 52 seconds
[debug] [IDB] Connecting idb service to '42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD'
[XCUITest] idb will not be used for Simulator interaction. Original error: 'idb' has not been found in PATH. Is it installed? Read https://www.fbidb.io for more details
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'simStarted' logged at 1568747084509 (14:04:44 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[debug] [XCUITest] Starting log capture for iOS Simulator with udid '42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD', using 'xcrun simctl spawn 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD log stream --style compact'
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'logCaptureStarted' logged at 1568747085347 (14:04:45 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[XCUITest] Using WDA path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
[XCUITest] Using WDA agent: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj'
[debug] [XCUITest] No obsolete cached processes from previous WDA sessions listening on port 8100 have been found
[debug] [XCUITest] Parsed BUILD_DIR configuration value: '/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products'
[debug] [XCUITest] Got derived data root: '/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy'
[debug] [XCUITest] Starting WebDriverAgent initialization with the synchronization key '/Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":8100}
[debug] [XCUITest] WDA is not listening at 'http://localhost:8100/'
[debug] [XCUITest] WDA is currently not running. There is nothing to cache
[debug] [XCUITest] Trying to start WebDriverAgent 2 times with 10000ms interval
[debug] [XCUITest] These values can be customized by changing wdaStartupRetries/wdaStartupRetryInterval capabilities
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1568747091183 (14:04:51 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
[debug] [XCUITest] Carthage found: '/usr/local/bin/carthage'
[debug] [XCUITest] Killing running processes 'xcodebuild.*42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD, iproxy 8100, 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD.*XCTRunner' for the device 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD...
[debug] [XCUITest] 'pgrep -ifn xcodebuild.*42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[debug] [XCUITest] 'pgrep -ifn iproxy 8100' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[debug] [XCUITest] 'pgrep -ifn 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD.*XCTRunner' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[debug] [XCUITest] Beginning test with command 'xcodebuild build-for-testing test-without-building -project /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgent.xcodeproj -scheme WebDriverAgentRunner -derivedDataPath /Users/patrick/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy -destination id=42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=13.0 GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS=0 COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO' in directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent'
[debug] [XCUITest] Output from xcodebuild will only be logged if any errors are present there. To change this, use 'showXcodeLog' desired capability
[debug] [XCUITest] Waiting up to 60000ms for WebDriverAgent to start
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":8100}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response: {"errno":"ECONNREFUSED","code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":8100}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : {\n    \"state\" : \"success\",\n    \"os\" : {\n      \"name\" : \"iOS\",\n      \"version\" : \"13.0\",\n      \"sdkVersion\" : \"13.0\"\n    },\n    \"ios\" : {\n      \"simulatorVersion\" : \"13.0\",\n      \"ip\" : \"192.168.0.41\"\n    },\n    \"build\" : {\n      \"upgradedAt\" : \"1568745012654\",\n      \"time\" : \"Sep 17 2019 13:34:34\",\n      \"productBundleIdentifier\" : \"com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"sessionId\" : \"27F6F5EA-539D-4088-9657-400A8686C4CA\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"
[debug] [WD Proxy] Determined that the downstream protocol for proxy is MJSONWP
[debug] [XCUITest] WebDriverAgent information:
[debug] [XCUITest] {
[debug] [XCUITest]   "state": "success",
[debug] [XCUITest]   "os": {
[debug] [XCUITest]     "name": "iOS",
[debug] [XCUITest]     "version": "13.0",
[debug] [XCUITest]     "sdkVersion": "13.0"
[debug] [XCUITest]   },
[debug] [XCUITest]   "ios": {
[debug] [XCUITest]     "simulatorVersion": "13.0",
[debug] [XCUITest]     "ip": "192.168.0.41"
[debug] [XCUITest]   },
[debug] [XCUITest]   "build": {
[debug] [XCUITest]     "upgradedAt": "1568745012654",
[debug] [XCUITest]     "time": "Sep 17 2019 13:34:34",
[debug] [XCUITest]     "productBundleIdentifier": "com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner"
[debug] [XCUITest]   }
[debug] [XCUITest] }
[debug] [XCUITest] WebDriverAgent successfully started after 15687ms
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1568747107016 (14:05:07 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"com.apple.mobilesafari","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true}}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{"sessionId":"18604E24-D247-4A43-A4A8-5B8F7FCB9D54","capabilities":{"device":"iphone","browserName":"Safari","sdkVersion":"13.0","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.mobilesafari"}},"sessionId":"18604E24-D247-4A43-A4A8-5B8F7FCB9D54","status":0}
[debug] [WD Proxy] Determined that the downstream protocol for proxy is MJSONWP
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionStarted' logged at 1568747113342 (14:05:13 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStarted' logged at 1568747113343 (14:05:13 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[XCUITest] Skipping setting of the initial display orientation. Set the "orientation" capability to either "LANDSCAPE" or "PORTRAIT", if this is an undesired behavior.
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'orientationSet' logged at 1568747113345 (14:05:13 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))

[debug] [iOS] Selecting by url: true (expected url: 'http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome')
[RemoteDebugger] Remote Debugger version 4.4.1
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] useNewSafari --> false
[RemoteDebugger] Setting communication protocol: using Target-based communication
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Connecting to remote debugger through unix domain socket: '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Uf5EaEsH0s/com.apple.webinspectord_sim.socket'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Debugger socket connected
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending connection key request
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_reportIdentifier:' message to remote debugger (id: 0)
[HTTP] --> GET /welcome
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [HTTP] Sending welcome response with params: {"message":"Let's browse!"}
[HTTP] <-- GET /welcome 200 83 ms - 124
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] <-- GET /favicon.ico 200 3 ms - 1150
[HTTP] 
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Notified of connected drivers: {}.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Connected to application
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Selecting application
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current applications available:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31843'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "Safari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "com.apple.mobilesafari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:31843' for bundle 'com.apple.mobilesafari'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Trying out the possible app ids: PID:31843
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Selecting app PID:31843 (try #1 of 20)
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardGetListing:' message to remote debugger (id: 1)
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] We were notified we might have connected to the wrong app. Using id PID:31846 instead of PID:31843
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Notified that new application 'PID:31846' has connected
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:31843' for bundle 'com.apple.mobilesafari'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found separate bundleId 'process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent' acting as proxy for 'com.apple.mobilesafari', with app id 'PID:31846'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Using proxied app id 'PID:31846'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Error checking application: 'New application has connected'. Retrying connection
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current applications available:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31843'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "Safari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "com.apple.mobilesafari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31846'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31846"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: true
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray: 'Waiting for data'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found app id key 'PID:31843' for bundle 'com.apple.mobilesafari'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Found separate bundleId 'process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent' acting as proxy for 'com.apple.mobilesafari', with app id 'PID:31846'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Trying out the possible app ids: PID:31843, PID:31846
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Selecting app PID:31843 (try #2 of 20)
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardGetListing:' message to remote debugger (id: 2)
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received response from socket send: '["PID:31843",{"1":{"WIRTitleKey":"Appium/welcome","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeWeb","WIRURLKey":"http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome","WIRPageIdentifierKey":1}}]'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received response from socket send: '["PID:31843",{"1":{"WIRTitleKey":"Appium/welcome","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeWeb","WIRURLKey":"http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome","WIRPageIdentifierKey":1}}]'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current applications available:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31843'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "Safari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "com.apple.mobilesafari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]           - id: 1
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             title: "Appium/welcome"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             url: "http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             isKey: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31846'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31846"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: true
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray: 'Waiting for data'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: {
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]   "1": {
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     "WIRTitleKey": "Appium/welcome",
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     "WIRTypeKey": "WIRTypeWeb",
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     "WIRURLKey": "http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome",
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     "WIRPageIdentifierKey": 1
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]   }
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] }
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received page change notice for app 'PID:31843' but listening for 'PID:31846'. Ignoring.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Notified that application 'PID:31843' has been updated
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received response from socket send: '["PID:31843",{"1":{"WIRTitleKey":"Appium/welcome","WIRTypeKey":"WIRTypeWeb","WIRURLKey":"http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome","WIRPageIdentifierKey":1}}]'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received page change notice for app 'PID:31843' but the listing has not changed. Ignoring.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received altered app id, updating from 'PID:31846' to 'PID:31843'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Waiting for 1 pages to be fulfilled
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current applications available:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31843'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "Safari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "com.apple.mobilesafari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]           - id: 1
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             title: "Appium/welcome"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             url: "http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             isKey: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31846'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31846"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: true
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray: []
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: {}
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received page change notice for app 'PID:31846' but listening for 'PID:31843'. Ignoring.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Notified that application 'PID:31846' has been updated
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current applications available:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31843'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "Safari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "com.apple.mobilesafari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]           - id: 1
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             title: "Appium/welcome"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             url: "http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             isKey: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31846'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31846"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: true
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray: []
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Finally selecting app PID:31843: [{"id":1,"title":"Appium/welcome","url":"http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome","isKey":false}]
[debug] [iOS] Picking webview 'WEBVIEW_31843.1'
[debug] [iOS] Attempting to set context to 'WEBVIEW_31843.1'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Selecting page '1' on app 'PID:31843' and forwarding socket setup
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardSocketSetup:' message to remote debugger (id: 3)
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sender key set
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Target created: {"targetId":"page-6","type":"page"}
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received page change notice for app 'PID:31843' but the listing has not changed. Ignoring.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Notified that application 'PID:31843' has been updated
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Notified that new application 'PID:31861' has connected
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current applications available:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31843'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "Safari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "com.apple.mobilesafari"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: undefined
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray:
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]           - id: 1
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             title: "Appium/welcome"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             url: "http://192.168.0.41:4723/welcome"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]             isKey: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31846'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31846"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: true
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 2
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray: []
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]     Application: 'PID:31861'
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         id: "PID:31861"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isProxy: true
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         name: "com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         bundleId: "process-com.apple.WebKit.WebContent"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         hostId: "PID:31843"
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isActive: 1
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         isAutomationEnabled: false
[debug] [RemoteDebugger]         pageArray: []
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Page changed: {}
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Received page change notice for app 'PID:31861' but listening for 'PID:31843'. Ignoring.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Notified that application 'PID:31861' has been updated
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Sending '_rpc_forwardSocketData:' message to remote debugger (id: 4)
[XCUITest] Error: Remote debugger error with code '-32000': Target not found.
[XCUITest]     at Object.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/lib/remote-debugger-rpc-client.js:254:18)
[XCUITest]     at RpcMessageHandler.handleDataMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/lib/remote-debugger-message-handler.js:194:9)
[XCUITest]     at RpcMessageHandler.handleMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/lib/remote-debugger-message-handler.js:77:13)
[XCUITest]     at RemoteDebuggerRpcClient.handleMessage [as receive] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/lib/remote-debugger-rpc-client.js:402:35)
[XCUITest]     at Socket.emit (events.js:209:13)
[XCUITest]     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
[XCUITest]     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:11)
[XCUITest]     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
[XCUITest]     at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23)
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/session/23f10772-5375-4c81-9536-5805132fc717' to command name 'deleteSession'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [DELETE /session/23f10772-5375-4c81-9536-5805132fc717] to [DELETE http://localhost:8100/session/18604E24-D247-4A43-A4A8-5B8F7FCB9D54] with no body
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:31843' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current app is PID:31843
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] No longer have app id. Attempting to find new one.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:31846' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current app is undefined
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Application 'PID:31861' disconnected. Removing from app dictionary.
[debug] [RemoteDebugger] Current app is undefined
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: "{\n  \"value\" : {\n\n  },\n  \"sessionId\" : \"33A93B5F-A13E-4C1B-B2DE-D243AEC0A4C4\",\n  \"status\" : 0\n}"
[debug] [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[debug] [XCUITest] Deleting simulator created for this run (udid: '42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD')
[debug] [XCUITest] Killing running processes 'xcodebuild.*42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD, 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD.*XCTRunner' for the device 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD...
[XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code 'null' and signal 'SIGTERM'
[debug] [XCUITest] 'pgrep -ifn xcodebuild.*42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[debug] [XCUITest] 'pgrep -ifn 42D158FC-3300-43BF-81A3-5B18B783FEDD.*XCTRunner' didn't detect any matching processes. Return code: 1
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1568747136388 (14:05:36 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Remote debugger error with code '-32000': Target not found.
[debug] [W3C]     at Object.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/lib/remote-debugger-rpc-client.js:254:18)
[debug] [W3C]     at RpcMessageHandler.handleDataMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/lib/remote-debugger-message-handler.js:194:9)
[debug] [W3C]     at RpcMessageHandler.handleMessage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/lib/remote-debugger-message-handler.js:77:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at RemoteDebuggerRpcClient.handleMessage [as receive] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/lib/remote-debugger-rpc-client.js:402:35)
[debug] [W3C]     at Socket.emit (events.js:209:13)
[debug] [W3C]     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
[debug] [W3C]     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:11)
[debug] [W3C]     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
[debug] [W3C]     at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 106926 ms - 615
[HTTP]
```

Comment: I'm also facing same problem. Can you please let me know how you resolved it ?

Comment: @Vasanth did not solve, think its a bug

Comment: @astronougt then what approach you followed for end to end testing of your application ?

Comment: @Vasanth I am using Browerstack for this

Answer (score 1):

```
Encountered internal error running command: Error: Remote debugger error with code '-32000': Target not found.
```

That means that you did not provide app to start, your driver initialized successfully ( `[debug] [XCUITest] WebDriverAgent successfully started after 15687ms` ) but since there is no application to start, nothing happens. Add `app` capability to start application.

Comment: I want to start Safari, docs say leave app blank.  http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/mobile-web/

Comment: Ok, what versions are you using? XCode, Appium?